# gm convert: FreeType library is not available after upgrading Heroku app to cedar 14

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, cedar

I have a Node.js app running on heroku.
It has been working fine until it was upgraded to cedar-14 recently.
When the app is trying to write a text on an image using gm library, this error will occur:

"gm convert: FreeType library is not available (font.otf) [No such file or directory]."

If I run "heroku run gm -version", this is the output on the cedar-14 app:

```
Feature Support:

Thread Safe              yes
Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
BZIP                     yes
DPS                      no
FlashPix                 no
FreeType                 no
Ghostscript (Library)    no
JBIG                     yes
JPEG-2000                yes
JPEG                     yes
Little CMS               yes
Loadable Modules         no
OpenMP                   yes (201107)
PNG                      yes
TIFF                     yes
TRIO                     no
UMEM                     no
WMF                      no
X11                      yes
XML                      yes
ZLIB                     yes
```

It appears that freetype is disabled. This is the buildpacks I am using:

```
https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

How to turn on freetype library on cedar-14 on heroku?